# Android Chatting Application Suggestion

Tags: android, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

My amigos and I are planning to make a instant messaging (chatting) application, something like weChat/Line/Kakao Talk, etc. Of course there are going to be little bits and pieces which will differentiate it from the other thousands of chat apps, but it is still a chat application.

So I was thinking about how this app will work, and I have some questions about server and database that I should make

My original thought was have MySQL as database and use XMPP server to deliver messages between devices

But I read about something called Google Cloud Messaging and from what I heard, it can be used to do what I'm looking for so I have few questions:

1. I think we need an online database to store user information and more extras. Can GCM be used along with a MySQL database?
2. Ultimately, we plan to earn money with this app, is it all right for me to use this and earn money (no matter how minuscule)?

Comment: Yes, GCM can be used along with MySql and GCM works as XMPP server between your server and android devices.

Comment: Does that mean that the server that i am implementing doesn't have to be xmpp server?

Comment: Yes and you have to implement the program to talk to gcm via xmpp.